# I have installed Elasticsearch 2.1.0

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

After configuring and installing Elasticsearch I got this error while checking the logs.

```
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,223][WARN ][bootstrap                ] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12,reason=Cannot allocate memory
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,223][WARN ][bootstrap                ] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,224][WARN ][bootstrap                ] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 65536, hard limit: 65536
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,224][WARN ][bootstrap                ] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example:
        # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
        elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
        elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,224][WARN ][bootstrap                ] If you are logged in interactively, you will have to re-login for the new limits to take effect.
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,428][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] version[2.1.0], pid[13298], build[72cd1f1/2015-11-18T22:40:03Z]
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,428][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] initializing ...
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,508][INFO ][plugins                  ] [node-1] loaded [], sites []
[2016-01-25 15:37:33,528][INFO ][env                      ] [node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [43.8gb], net total_space [49.9gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
[2016-01-25 15:37:35,022][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] initialized
[2016-01-25 15:37:35,022][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] starting ...
[2016-01-25 15:37:35,088][INFO ][transport                ] [node-1] publish_address {10.155.153.74:9300}, bound_addresses {10.155.153.74:9300}
[2016-01-25 15:37:35,097][INFO ][discovery                ] [node-1] Elasticsearch/M0pCcU6UQ1ShHxlOZ4U22w
[2016-01-25 15:37:38,157][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [node-1] new_master {node-1}{M0pCcU6UQ1ShHxlOZ4U22w}{10.155.153.74}{10.155.153.74:9300}{master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-01-25 15:37:38,195][INFO ][http                     ] [node-1] publish_address {10.155.153.74:9200}, bound_addresses {10.155.153.74:9200}
[2016-01-25 15:37:38,196][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] started
[2016-01-25 15:37:38,250][INFO ][gateway                  ] [node-1] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2016-01-25 15:37:45,458][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [node-1] [.kibana] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [1]/[1], mappings [config
```

I checked for bootstrap.mlockall: true too . 
Elasticsearch.yml file

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
  cluster.name: Elasticsearch
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
  node.name: node-1
  node.master: true
  node.data: true
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
  bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
  network.host: 10.155.153.74
  network.publish_host: 10.155.153.74
  network.bind_host: 10.155.153.74
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
  http.port: 9200
  discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

# http.cors.enabled: true
# http.cors.allow-origin: http://tvmatp326579d.ad.infosys.com:5601/
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Elasticsearch nodes will find each other via unicast, by default.
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
# action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Can anybody tell what could be the issue? why ES is not able to lock JVM memory?

update:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you set the environment variable? ES_HEAP_SIZE ?

Comment: yes i changed the value it is resolved :) but now i have another issue. The ES is still yellow and node is not starting.

Comment: paste your error log if possible, and also make sure that port 9200 and 9300 are not blocked by firewall

Comment: almost done with this issue too. but i am not able to open the kibana UI. the service script i made for kibana is :[Unit]
Description=Kibana 4 Web Interface
After=elasticsearch.service
After=logstash.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=rm -rf /var/run/kibana.pid
ExecStart=/opt/kibana4/bin/kibana/
ExecReload=kill -9 $(cat /var/run/kibana.pid) && rm -rf /var/run/kibana.pid && /opt/kibana4/bin/kibana/
ExecStop=kill -9 $(cat /var/run/kibana.pid)
[Install]  and currently elasticsearch and logstash both are running just logstash-forwarder isnt installed yet!

Comment: after starting kibana service I get this message kibana4.service - Kibana 4 Web Interface
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana4.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-01-25 21:01:29 IST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 24915 (node)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana4.service
           ââ24915 /opt/kibana4/bin/../node/bin/node /opt/kibana4/bin/../src/cli   Starting Kibana 4 Web Interface...

Comment: try adding this as a different question

Answer (score -1):

Set the environment variable

**ES_HEAP_SIZE**

Ref: [Heap sizing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#heap-sizing)

question 2: (in comments)

make sure that port 9200 and 9300 are not blocked by firewall

Comment: checked these things and they are working fine now but still i am getting blank page for kibana UI

Comment: share your screen snapshot by updating the question

Comment: And make sure you've made valid kibana configuration file,

chrome sometimes blocks the calls, try using firefox or some other browser for a test.

most common issue will be setting the path in config

Comment: seems like i am not able to attach the images

Comment: [Unit]
Description=Kibana 4 Web Interface
After=elasticsearch.service
After=logstash.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=rm -rf /var/run/kibana.pid
ExecStart=/opt/kibana4/bin/kibana/
ExecReload=kill -9 $(cat /var/run/kibana.pid) && rm -rf /var/run/kibana.pid && /opt/kibana4/bin/kibana/
ExecStop=kill -9 $(cat /var/run/kibana.pid)
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~
the kibana service file

Comment: The error I got while loading the kibana UI : The connection has timed out

The server at domain is taking too long to respond.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: make sure the firewall is not blocking 5601 port

Comment: have stopped iptables to disable the firewall

Comment: From your snapshot, it clearly showing that kibana is not loaded properly.

try loading the url http://localhost:5601 or try loading using http://<your ip>:5601

Comment: tried that too same error is coming at that time too! and localhost won't work due to the configs

Comment: and when i am checking the status of the kibana service it is showing active state and no errors in the log file

Comment: then the problem may exist with your URL

Comment: In your kibana.yml file, there is a configuration for Elastic Search (ES) instance. elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"

Comment: have checked the DNS entry too. earlier the issue was with the DNS entry but now i am not able to identify the issue!

Comment: yes that is there already! i modified it to the current hostname instead of localhost!

Comment: check whether kibana is running in 5601 or some other port in log file

Comment: got this message in log file when tried curl command {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2016-01-25T17:36:44+00:00","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":27708,"message":"Server running at http://10.155.153.74:5601"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2016-01-25T18:01:59+00:00","tags":[],"pid":27708,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/","method":"get","headers":{"user-agent":"curl/7.29.0","host":"hostname:5601","accept":"*/*"},"remoteAddress":"10.155.153.74","userAgent":"10.155.153.74"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":66,"contentLength":9},

Comment: try using 10‌​.155.153.74:5601

and also make sure that Es instance also running

Comment: already tried and it is not working at all!! when I tried curl -XGET 10.155.153.74:5601 at that time I got the above output